# Focus UITextField in TableViewCell on tvOS

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, tvos

in my AppleTV app, I have a custom UITableViewCell with UITextField inside.

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to focus this text field to enter text in it.

Unfortunately only the cell itself is focussing, I'm not able to focus the text field.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cell is getting focused because it returns `YES` from `canBecomeFocused`. If you want something within the cell to become focused, the cell needs to start returning `NO` from that method. There are two ways to do that: using the table view delegate method, or by subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

In your table view's delegate, you can implement the method `tableView:canFocusRowAtIndexPath:` and return `NO` for the cells that contain text fields.

Or, in your subclass of `UITableViewCell`, you could override `canBecomeFocused` to return `NO`.

Comment: that won't work because a child can't be focused when its parent is not focusable.

Comment: Jess, that is not correct. For example, UIWindow returns NO from canBecomeFocused, but obviously it's children are focusable.

Comment: Justin Voss's answer is working perfectly ! I did override the canBecomeFocused method in my subclass and now it selects the textfields and I can navigate from one textfield to one other :)

Comment: @JustinVoss you are correct. I must be confusing it with another condition where that rule is in effect. I've seen _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable return that rule for some views.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the UITableViewCell and set the preferredFocusedView of the cell to the UITextField.

```
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@end

@implementation TableViewCell
...
- (UIView*)preferredFocusedView {
  return self.textField;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is allowing me to focus the textField instead of the cell itself, but I would also like to be able to focus others textfields of other cells but it seems that the focus is blocked in the cell ...